# How to calculate xlsx columns width from page coordinates?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, birt

I am trying to write my custom Birt XSLX emitter. I am using birt 4.6 and everything is working just fine, but when I try to calculate column width using page coordinates it's not calculated properly.

```
@Override
public void endSheet(Page page, String orientation, int pageWidth, int pageHeight, float leftMargin,
        float rightMargin, float topMargin, float bottomMargin) {
        double[] coordinates = page.getCoordinates();
        for (byte i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
            this.sheet.setColumnWidth(i, (int) countXlsxColWidth(coordinates[i]/1000.0D, 96) * 256);
        
        }
}


 public static double countXlsxColWidth(double paramDouble, int paramInt) {
        float pixels = 72.0F / paramInt;
        double d1 = 0.0D;
        double d2 = paramDouble / pixels;
        double d3 = 7.0D;
        if (d2 < 12.0D)
          return d2 / 12.0D; 
        d1 = (int)((d2 - 5.0D) / d3 * 100.0D + 0.5D);
        double d4 = d1 / 100.0D;
        d1 = (int)(d4 * d3 / d3 * 256.0D);
        return d1 / 256.0D;
      }
```

Does any one has any idea how to calculate column width in birt XLSX emitter properly using page coordinates?

Comment: Can't help, but - why are you trying to create your own emitter? Why not use the "spudsoft emitter"?

Comment: @hvb Yes "spudsoft emitter" is there but it is not good for all elements, merging, widths etc. So I have written my own which is working well just I am stuck at this width calculation,

Comment: If you are able to write your own emitter, you should probably the birt-dev mailing list. Maybe someone there can help you. Your calculations seem rather magic to me. I know some of the constants like 256 and 1000 from my own excel width calculations , but for example, what is the source of the constant 96? And you should write your code more readable - variables and parameters should have meaningful names.

Comment: 96 is dpi, 72 is pixels, 12 is for font etc.